# Android 端末によっては、 AsyncTaskが二回呼ばれてしまう

Tags: android

Nexus 5 でプログラムを実行すると `AsyncTask` は一回しか呼ばれなかったのですが、今度は Xperia でプログラムを実行すると `AsyncTask` が二回呼ばれてしまいました。端末が違えば挙動がおかしくなるというバグが `AsyncTask` にはあったりするのでしょうか？以下にソースコードを記します。ログを取ってみると、 `PostTwitter` クラスの `doInBackground()` と、 `TwitterOAuth` クラスの`getAccessToken()` の `doInBackground()`がそれぞれ二回呼ばれていました。つまり Twitter への投稿が二回されてしまいます。これは `AsyncTask` の使い方が何か間違っているのでしょうか？すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

`PostTwitter` クラス:

```
public class PostTwitter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Twitter mTwitter;

    public PostTwitter(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void shareTwitter() {
        if (TwitterUtils.hasAccessToken(mActivity.getApplicationContext())) {
            share(mActivity);
        } else {
            TwitterOAuth twitterOAuth = new TwitterOAuth(mActivity);
            twitterOAuth.startAuthorize();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image.png");
            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(params[0]); {
                status.setMedia(file);
            }
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
            return true;
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            showToast("ツイートが完了しました！");
        } else {
            showToast("ツイートに失敗しました。。。");
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void share(Activity activity) {
        PostTwitter task = new PostTwitter(activity);
        task.execute(TwitterContents.getInstance().getmMessage());
    }
}
```

`TwitterOAuth` クラス:

```
public class TwitterOAuth {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private String mCallbackURL;
    private Twitter mTwitter;
    private RequestToken mRequestToken;
    private String mOAuthURL;
    private String mOAuthVerifier;

    public TwitterOAuth(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mCallbackURL = activity.getString(R.string.twitter_callback_url);
        mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(activity);
    }

    public void startAuthorize() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    mRequestToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(mCallbackURL);
                    mOAuthURL = mRequestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
                    return mOAuthURL;
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
                if (url != null) {
                    showTwitterDialog();
                } else {
                    // 失敗。。。
                }
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }

    private void getAccessToken() {
        AsyncTask<String, Void, AccessToken> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, AccessToken>() {
            @Override
            protected AccessToken doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    return mTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(mRequestToken, params[0]);
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(AccessToken accessToken) {
                TwitterUtils.storeAccessToken(mActivity, accessToken);
                PostTwitter postTwitter = new PostTwitter(mActivity);
                postTwitter.share(mActivity);
            }
        };
        task.execute(mOAuthVerifier);
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTaskの"何が"2回呼ばれるかを明記した方が良いと思います。`doInBackground`のオーバーライドでしょうか？またAsyncTask（を継承したクラス）を、どこで作成しているかも要因となりえるかと。

Comment: もし可能でしたら、問題を再現する小さなコードサンプルを載せたほうが、憶測で議論が進まずに済むかもしれません。

Comment: yohjpさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。お返事が遅くなり申し訳ございません。doInBackgroundが二回呼ばれていました。全体が把握しずらいのでソースコードを載せたいと思います。すみません。

Comment: 3100さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。はい、ソースコードを載せたいと思います。

Comment: doInBackground()は3つありますがどれのことを言っていますか？execute()が呼ばれたのは間違いなく1回ですか？`PostTwitter#share`の中で`PostTwitter task = new PostTwitter(activity);`をやってるのは奇妙に思えるのですが、意図した物ですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。解決することができました！結論から申しますと、AsyncTaskとは別のところで処理がおかしくなっていました。てっきりAsyncTaskがおかしいものと思い、AsyncTaskに関するコードしか載せず、申し訳ありませんでした。詳細は自分で回答しようと思います。今までAsyncTaskをぼんやりと使っていたのですが、suzukisさんのご指摘でAsyncTaskが理解でき、そのおかげでエラーを解決することができました。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTaskはAPI 13からバッググラウンドでの処理が並列ではなくなっているので、

仮に、端末のOSのバージョンが違って

仮に、AsyncTaskの処理が同期されてない複数回呼ばれるものだったら

二回呼ばれることがあったり、なかったりするかもしれませんね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
やはり複数回AsyncTaskが呼ばれるようなことはあり得るのですね。。。
これを回避する方法などはあるのでしょうか？（AsyncTaskLoaderを使うとか？）

Answer (score 1):

解決することができました。
実際にはAsyncTaskとは別のところで処理がおかしくなっていました。
そのおかしくなっていた場所がダイアログを表示させる部分で、以下のコードの`onPageStarted`や`onPageFinished`が二回呼ばれていました。調べてみると、どうやら端末によって複数回呼ばれたりすることがたまにあるみたいです。なので、`onPageFinished`の`if (!mIsPageFinished)`のようにして一度だけ処理させることで一回のみのツイートを行うことができました。

```
     public void showTwitterDialog() {
        final Dialog twitterDialog = new Dialog(mActivity); {
            twitterDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            twitterDialog.setContentView(R.layout.twitter_dialog);
            WebView webView = (WebView) twitterDialog.findViewById(R.id.twitter_webview);
            webView.loadUrl(mOAuthURL);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    if (!mIsPageFinished) {
                        if (url.contains("oauth_verifier")) {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                            mOAuthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                            twitterDialog.dismiss();
                            getAccessToken();
                            mIsPageFinished = true;
                        } else if (url.contains("denied")) {
                            twitterDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            twitterDialog.show();
        }
    }
```